# Access to storage.cloud.google.com with a service account

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-storage

Posted this on [github](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/154#event-1523083217) and was told to come here ask for help

---

Hello!

I am trying to implement custom authentication for my resources on Google Cloud Storage using [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) with a service account. I am trying to abstract away the need for a Google account for my end users.

What the ideal workflow would look like:

1. User queries `https://cdn.example.com/[[BUCKET]]/[[FILENAME]]` using Bearer token
2. The API on that end intercepts the bucket and file name and checks the validity of the token
3. The API then would request the resource at `https://storage.cloud.google.com/[[BUCKET]]/[[FILENAME]]`
4. `Step 3` Returns the `Location` header that I will pass over to the user

After snooping around a bit I found out that the `Location` header returned in `step 3` in the form of `https://[[DATA]].googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/[[BUCKET]]/o/[[FILENAME]]?qk=[[KEY]]` is a public link that can be accessed by anonymous users too. Which is exactly what I want. However while using the storage API I can only see `selfLink` and `mediaLink`, not the link above.

I tried using [`google-auto-auth`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auto-auth) to sign the request with my service account towards the `storage.cloud.google.com` endpoint but I get an `Unauthorized` error.

From looking [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/cookie-based-authentication) I understand that to access the `storage.cloud.google.com` is based on cookie authentication, which `google-auto-auth` doesn't seem to do. All it does is add a Bearer token to the header of the request.

**This looks like you need [signedUrls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)**

Yea, that would be great, if it didn't expose the email of the service account.

Cheers!

TL;DR How to get the redirect URL from `storage.cloud.google.com` links using a service account?

Comment: There are several points I would like to clarify. 1. What is the issue with signedURLs having the SA email exposed? If that was an issue, it would for sure not be the proposed method to access protected resources in GCS. - 2. According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_accessing), using such a `storage.cloud.google.com` link will always require the authentication with a Google account. - 3. Does [making files public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) make sense in your use case?

Comment: 4. Google App Engine's Python library has [a method](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.images#google.appengine.api.images.get_serving_url), `get_serving_url()` that provides a URL that serves the underlying image. However, it is not available in NodeJS, as this is part of the GAE Images library and not Cloud Storage.

Comment: 1. That's mostly for security through obfuscation.

2. Yes, that does cookie authentication for users. I want to know if there's other auth methods for SA.

3. Files can't be public.

4. Does this make a signedURL aswell or does it work different? Is there source code for how this works? This seems to just provide resizing and cropping functionality, not security.

Comment: 2. I don't think there is any other way of authenticating using SA without exposing it, rather than making the requests directly from another service such as App Engine, which also use a SA for authentication.
4. It does not make a signedURL, instead it creates a different serving URL which is *publicly accessible but not guessable*, as stated in [this documentation page with some more information](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images/#get-serving-url). Cropping is just an additional functionality, and it will be using GAE's SA for the authentication against GCS.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need but in node.js and without the App Engine requirement as my code is running on containers under Kubernetes.

Comment: It is only available in the GAE Images API, and works only with images, in GAE Standard and not in NodeJS, unfortunately. The issue here is that the use case that you present is covered by Signed URLs. You can create a SA with narrow scopes (just [storage.objectViewer](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#roles) for example) so that it is used only for the purpose of reading from GCS, and then you should not worry about its info being exposed. I have been trying to figure out alternatives using Bearer Tokens or other approaches, but I could not find anything else.